E/flutter (10916): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Reflecting on type `OptionGroup` without capability
E/flutter (10916): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: Reflecting on type `OptionGroup` without capability
E/flutter (10916): #0      ReflectableImpl.reflectType (package:reflectable/src/reflectable_builder_based.dart:2576:7)

E/flutter (10916): #1      Repository.entity (package:d2_touch/core/utilities/repository.dart:717:31)

E/flutter (10916): #2      new BaseQuery (package:d2_touch/shared/queries/base.query.dart:49:33)

E/flutter (10916): #3      new OptionGroupQuery (package:d2_touch/modules/metadata/option_group/queries/option_group.query.dart:7:44)

E/flutter (10916): #4      OptionGroupModule.createTables (package:d2_touch/modules/metadata/option_group/option_group.module.dart:8:11)

E/flutter (10916): #5      D2Touch.setDatabase (package:d2_touch/d2_touch.dart:156:29)

E/flutter (10916): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (10916): #6      D2Touch.init (package:d2_touch/d2_touch.dart:110:9)

E/flutter (10916): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (10916): #7      main (package:user_support_mobile/main.dart:16:18)

E/flutter (10916): <asynchronous suspension>

E/flutter (10916): 

I was running my app, it was supposed to give me a log in form, but just resulted to a blank white space with that error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
